# Creating a list for the clustered environment

Tags: java, spring, rabbitmq, hazelcast, distributed-caching

In my application there is a list `publisherPostListenerList` which receives the real time user posts from the RabbitMQ queue to be sent to the subscribers/consumers. The list is a property of `ApplicationListener` class which listens to the events of the pubsub queue. The below controller method fetches the list elements via getter method & based on a logic pushes the posts to the subscribers.

The flow is as follows

User writes a post -> Post gets into DB + Queue -> Message from Queue is added in a list which is `publisherPostListenerList`to be pushed to the subscribers of the user.

As we can see the `publisherPostListenerList` is a common list for n concurrent requests due to `ApplicationListener` being a singleton. For a single instance the setup works fine but will fail in a clustered environment as each node will have its own individual `publisherPostListenerList` list.

How do I deal with this situation? I can't make `ApplicationListener` class stateless I need the list to store the post elements received from the queue. Do I put the list in a distributed in memory cache? Or there is any other conventional way?

**ApplicationListener.java**

```
@Component
public class ApplicationEventListener {

    private List<Post> publisherPostListenerList = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<Post>();

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(ApplicationEventListener.class);

    @EventListener
    public void postSubmissionEventHandler(PostSubmissionEvent event) throws IOException {
        Post post = event.getPost();
        logger.debug("application published user post received " + post);
        publisherPostListenerList.add(post);
    }

    public List<Post> getPublisherPostListenerList() {
        return publisherPostListenerList;
    }

    public void setPublisherPostListenerList(List<Post> publisherPostListenerList) {
        this.publisherPostListenerList = publisherPostListenerList;
    }
}
```

**Controller method for pushing the message to the subscriber**

```
@RequestMapping(value="/getRealTimeServerPushUserPosts")
    public SseEmitter getRealTimeServerPushUserPosts(@RequestParam("userId") int userId){
        SseEmitter sseEmitter = new SseEmitter();
        CustomUserDetail myUserDetails = currentUserAccessor.getCurrentLoggedInUser();
        User loggedInUser=myUserDetails.getUser();

        List<Integer> userPublisherIDList = this.userService.loadUserPublisherIdListWhichLoggedInUserFollows(loggedInUser);
        List<Post> postList =eventListener.getPublisherPostListenerList();


        for(Integer userPublisherId : userPublisherIDList){
            for(Post post:postList){
                    if((userPublisherId.intValue()) == (post.getUser().getUserId().intValue())){
                        try {
                        sseEmitter.send(post);
                        postList.remove(post); //removes the post for all the subscribers as the list acts as a global list.
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        logger.error(e);
                    }
                }
             }
         }
        return sseEmitter;
    }
```

Comment: who will invoke the controller method ?

Comment: I am using server sent events to push the message to the client/loggedInUser

Comment: why can't u use database instead ?

Comment: When a user creates a post I am pushing both to the db & the queue. Pushing to the queue saves the db hits as the system pushes the real time post to the user subscribers from the queue.

Comment: Can you use a JMS queue ?, with it you will be able to store the events and retrieve them safely in a cluster enviroment.

Comment: @karelss I am using RabbitMQ queue, from that queue I take the elements in the ApplicationListener.java class publisherPostListenerList list. Is there any other way to receive data from a distributed queue?

Comment: Are you sure that you have a queue and not a topic ? http://integrationspot.blogspot.com.es/2011/03/jms-queue-difference-between-queue-and.html, if you have a queue instead of receive an event, you can query the queue, if you query the queue each event is only process once, this is guaranteed by the queue

Comment: Here you have an example of how to do this with multiple consumers https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/jms/jms-queue-example/

Comment: @karelss Just like in the ex. given by you the message from the queue is received as a Text msg. Similarly in my case it's a Post object. The queue has several post objects so I have to maintain a list for several objects.

Comment: @underdog you don't need the list as far as i see, you can use your queue in the same way, you your code only show that you are reading the elements from the queue then you add this elements to the list and after that remove the elements on the push to suscribers phase. If you use a topic and you read on each instance (talking about a cluster) all the objects you have the same behaviour, what you need to do to avoid sending duplicate elements and keep bough lists synchronised is another topic where you post the elements that you already sent so before sending one.

Comment: Other thing that you can do if what you want is process only one each element without keeping them, is just have workers pulling the elements from the queue and processing each one

Comment: If you just want to share your list, use infinitespam or ehcache as you suggest, any distributed cache will do the job

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Hazelcast `IList`. It follows `j.u.List` semantics and suitable for distributed / clustered environments.

You can find a documentation [here](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#list) and examples [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-collections/list/src/main/java).
Another option is to use distributed map aka [`IMap`](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-dev/manual/html-single/index.html#map).

Let me know if you have specific questions regarding implementation details.

Thank you

Comment: I've decided to use IMap to store SseEmitters, but SseEmitter class is not serializable so I can not store it in distributed Hazelcast cache. Can you offer any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

Putting the list in a cached memory in the application could lead to several problems (like low scalability...). Why don't you use an in-memory database like Redis? In such way you can scale your app and all instances could share the same database. You also guarantee the data integrity.

Answer (score -1):

ApplicationListener is designed to be used to handle the events within application context. For solving your problem, you may need to deploy some message technology (JMS topic).
Instead of adding PostSubmmittion to a list, your postSubmissionEventHandler() will create and send a message to represent the event on a JMS topic. 
Now in your controller method, you can read the messages from topic and then publish them to the connected users.

Hope this helps